# Set size of \datavisualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-datavisualization

I am trying to plot the function
[image: f(x)]
using `\datavisualization` like this

```
\datavisualization [school book axes,
                visualize as smooth line,
                y axis={label},
                x axis={label} ]
data [format=function] {
  var x : interval [0:60] samples 60;
  func y = -(1/300000)*(\value x)^4 + (113/240000)*(\value x)^3 - (1063/48000)*(\value x)^2 + (1253/3200)*(\value x) - (871/640);
};
```

However, I get an error telling me the plot is too large (`Dimension too large.<to be read again>\relax l.87 };`).

How can I properly plot this function?

Answer (score 0):

The tikz user guide has the following to say about number accuracy:

[image]

This means that by using `(...)` you fall back to the tex accuracy and run into problems with too large numbers.

You can avoid the problem with this trick taken from [Is it possible to plot complicated functions with TikZ datavisualization?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518297/is-it-possible-to-plot-complicated-functions-with-tikz-datavisualization)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes,
                visualize as smooth line,
                y axis={label},
                x axis={label},
                /pgf/data/evaluator=\pgfmathparseFPU,
                x axis={length=.8\linewidth, ticks=few}
                 ]
data [format=function] {
  var x : interval [0:60] samples 60;
  func y = -1/300000*(\value x)^4 + 113/240000*(\value x)^3 - 1063/48000*(\value x)^2 + 1253/3200*(\value x) - (871/640);
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]