# Is it possible to plot complicated functions with TikZ datavisualization?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

Is it possible to plot complicated functions with TikZ datavisualization?

I have a transfer function `G(s)=2/(20*s+1)^5*2/s`. The inverse Laplace [transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+inverse&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%222%2F%2820*s%2B1%29%5E5*2%2Fs%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22s%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22laplace+inverse%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22) gives
`g(t)=4-(e^(-t/20)*(3840000+192000*t+4800*t^2+80*t^3+t^4))/960000` or expanded
`g(t)=-(e^(-t/20)*t^4)/960000-(e^(-t/20)*t^3)/12000-1/200*e^(-t/20)*t^2-1/5*e^(-t/20)*t-4*e^(-t/20)+4` and I have to plot `g` on the huge interval `[0,280]`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes={clean},
                       all axes = grid,
                       x axis = {label = $t$},
                       y axis = {label = $y(t)$},
                       visualize as smooth line
                      ]
    data[format = function]
    {
     var x : interval[0 : 280];
     %func y = 4 - (exp(-\value x/20) * (3840000 + 192000 * \value x + 4800 * \value x^2 + 80 * \value x^3 + \value x^4))/960000;
     func y = -(exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^4)/960000 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^3)/12000 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^2)/200 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x)/5 - 4 * exp(-\value x/20) + 4;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I naturally recive a

> Dimension too large.

error, which is clear.

I already asked a [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354071/dimension-too-large-errors-by-tikz-datavisualization) question. The solution was reducing the interval, but now it isn't possible. The result should looks like

[image: figure 1]

Is there a way to reproduce this plot with `TikZ datavisualization`?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Since you do have the plot, you should have access to he data points. Export them, plot them.

Comment: Hello @Johannes_B! Thank you for your comment! I know that this is possible. My wish is to plot it by the described way.

Comment: You should consider using pythontex, or other general programming interface suited for doing such dimension-heavy calculations. I often hear that TeX is not designed to do that.

Comment: Hello @Tomáš Kruliš! Thank you for your hint. But why I should invent the wheel, when its already invented. Of course one could use for example `matlab2tikz`, but than one get a huge cloud with data points, which is nearly impossible to maintain, please correct me, if I'am wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can use the `/pgf/data/evaluator` key to install locally `fpu` for the parsing. The macro `\pgfmathparseFPU`, which locally switches on `fpu`, is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501154/194703).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes={clean},
                       all axes = grid,
                       x axis = {label = $t$},
                       y axis = {label = $y(t)$},
                       visualize as smooth line,
                       /pgf/data/evaluator=\pgfmathparseFPU
                      ]
    data[format = function]
    {
     var x : interval[0 : 280];
     %func y = 4 - (exp(-\value x/20) * (3840000 + 192000 * \value x + 4800 * \value x^2 + 80 * \value x^3 + \value x^4))/960000;
     func y = -(exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^4)/960000 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^3)/12000 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^2)/200 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x)/5 - 4 * exp(-\value x/20) + 4;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the first function works, too.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes={clean},
                       all axes = grid,
                       x axis = {label = $t$},
                       y axis = {label = $y(t)$},
                       visualize as smooth line,
                       /pgf/data/evaluator=\pgfmathparseFPU
                      ]
    data[format = function]
    {
     var x : interval[0 : 280];
     func y = 4 - (exp(-\value x/20) * (3840000 + 192000 * \value x + 4800 * \value x^2 + 80 * \value x^3 + \value x^4))/960000;
     %func y = -(exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^4)/960000 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^3)/12000 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x^2)/200 - (exp(-\value x/20) * \value x)/5 - 4 * exp(-\value x/20) + 4;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Schrödinger's cat! Thank you for your answer! This is what I searched, really nice! Was it always there? Or is it new?

Comment: @Su-47 I think the key ` /pgf/data/evaluator` has been there for a while. But I am not sure, I am not a historian, just a cat. ;-)

Comment: Hello @Schrödinger's cat! Thank you for your comment! I have an [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348799/how-to-use-the-tikz-fpu-library) question releated to `fpu`.

Comment: Is it possible to shade the area below the graph, between to limits t=a and t=b, a>b?

Comment: @mf67 Please ask a separate question on this.