# TikZ datavisualization with plotted expression and shade

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

I tried to use the datavisualization command (that uses [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518297/is-it-possible-to-plot-complicated-functions-with-tikz-datavisualization) metod), an explicit function and shading, but it was more or less a 'dial it in' way of solving it, with having to scale the x and y coordinates with a factor 1.43 etc. Are there any better an a more 'solid' solution? TIA.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=100*exp(-0.24*\x)/14.3;}]
\datavisualization[
scientific axes={clean},
all axes = grid,
x axis = {length=7cm, min value=0, max value=10, grid={step=1}},
y axis = {length=7cm, min value=0, max value=100},
visualize as smooth line,
/pgf/data/evaluator=\pgfmathparseFPU
]
data[format = function]
{
 var x : interval[0:10];
func y = 100*exp(-0.24*\value x);
};

\draw[thick,dashed] (5/1.43,{f(5)})--(5/1.43,0);

Shade grey area underneath curve.
\fill [fill=black!60,opacity=.2] (0,0) -- plot[domain=0:5] ({\x/1.43},{f(\x)}) -- (5/1.43,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a complete document that is compilable as is. Even though you seem to have listed all relevant libraries, everyone who is willing to look at it will have to complete the document.

Comment: The factor `1.43` is of course nothing but `(x_max-x_min)/width=(10-0)/7`.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the code now with a full working document. Yes the scaling is as you say, but a but cumbersome to use. Is there a cleaner method than the above?